# Publishing a post that should appear in home page of my friends in facebook using api

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using `facebook graph api`, i'm able to post to my timeline. When i tried to post to other user it throws

```
Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application
```

later i found that it was removed. My requirement is to publish a post that should appear in home page of `my friends`.

what is the available way to share a post?

which api to use?

can any one help on this.

Comment: you cant post to the wall of another user. there is no way, luckily. what exactly would you post to the wall of another user with the api anyway?

Comment: you did not answer my question. what EXACTLY would you post to the wall of another user? what is the use case?

Comment: @luschn i have to post certificate image. use case-manager post the image that has to appear in employees facebook homepage.

Comment: send a link to the image with the send dialog then